# NDSolve with CUDALink

Tags: differential-equations, cudalink

I am solving a system of non linear differential equations. The time needed to solve them is quite long and I would like to shorten it.
Is it possible to send the NDSolve command to be solved by the GPU using CUDALink?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. If you could show your code there might be other ways to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no library that I am aware of that does the trick. So there is no easy solution on it. Anyway, there is a publication about CUDA and parabolic PDEs. Do a search on "CUDA Jahn Uni Bayreuth" in the internet. There is a pdf (diploma Dissertation). May be that helps to find a solution for your problem; adding the problem to learn German ;).